# How can I make the video fit the size of the viewport that is there before the page is scrolled?

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I have embedded a video into my page and I need to make the video fit the white area below in the image. That is the area which is there before the page is scrolled. When the page is scrolled the below contents should be visible as normal. What I mean is that this video is not full screen. But it should fit the view port before it is scrolled. Below is the white area I need to fill the video with. Also it should start at the top bar. And be transparent on the top bar where the social media links are available. Below is the image.

[image]

Below is the video html code I have now.

```
<video  autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid" >
            <source src="http://www.icins.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SLIDE-SHOW-NEW.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
```

I tried this CSS. But it fills the whole view port that the top bar is not at all visible. It gets covered by the video.

```
#video-landing {
width: auto; /* actually wider than viewport */
height: auto;
color: white;
background-size: cover;

}

#video-landing video {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: -200px; 
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0; width: 100px; height: 891px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

}

Also I can't hardcode the "top" element like I have been in my code since it might affect different screen resolutions. Any assistance is much appreciated as I am completely new to html and css.

This is what I get after I tried out bassie's answer below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting `z-index` property on the top bar so that it is higher than that of the video.

or, you should be able to set the video's height to `vh` and then use some jquery when the page loads to do `height = height - heightOfTopBar`

**Update**

The video, inside a div:

```
    <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="fullscreen-bg">   
        <video loop muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="http://www.icins.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SLIDE-SHOW-NEW.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> 
    </div>
```

css:

```
      .fullscreen-bg {

          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          z-index: -100;


          position:relative;
          height:100vh;     
        }

      .fullscreen-bg__video {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

        @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
          .fullscreen-bg__video {
            height: 300%;
            top: -100%;
          }
        }

        @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
          .fullscreen-bg__video {
            width: 300%;
            left: -100%;
          }
        }
      .header {
          position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
          height: 200px;
          background: yellow;
      }
```

Comment: Adding z-index doesn't make any difference. The top bar appears, and then it disappears as it is covered by my video.

Comment: did you set a z-index on both the video and the topbar? (z-index:0 and z-index:1)

Comment: Yes set for both things. But video doesn't fit the view port. Its half filled.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a similar attempt at what you want, hopefully that helps

Comment: I've added an image to the question with what I get after I put your answer in the code. Its almost there but the video doesn't cover the full white space as expected :(

Answer (score 0):

`#video-landing video` has `top: -200px;`

that will move the video UP (beyond the top of the container). If you want to move it further DOWN, use a positive value.

Also, setting width AND heigth to 100% might cause wrong proportions. Try `width: 100%` and `height: auto`